# IOS- how to pick multiple images in UIImagePickerController

Tags: uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

how to pick multiple images in UIImagePickerController in uiimageview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the github code link..[GitHub Link](https://github.com/sgxiang/YSQImagePickerController)

In this link you got all the solutions of the problem